# How do we get geometry data type of huge dataset from PostGIS in very less time in python?

Tags: python, performance, geometry, geospatial

I have a table in PostGIS that has around 4 million records. Now I am trying to fetch all those records in python script. For that I am using following code snippet:

##### Code Snippet

```
import pandas.io.sql as psql
import psycopg2
from shapely import wkt
import geopandas

query = "SELECT id, ST_AsText(geom) as geometry FROM <table>"

def postgresql_conn(user, postgres_password, host, port, database):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user=user, password=postgres_password, host=host, port=port, database=database)
    return connection

conn = postgresql_conn(user, postgres_password, host, port, postgresql_database)
df = psql.read_sql(query, conn)
print(df.dtypes)
```

When I see the output the **geometry column** is an **object data type** instead of **geometry data type**. This is because it is in a string format. However, how do I get that in **geometry data type** while fetching from the database itself?
I have tried to convert it into **geometry data type** using following command after I fetched it from database:

##### Code Snippet

```
df['geometry'] = geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df['geometry'])
df= geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='geometry')
```

*It is taking **more than an hour** just to convert 4 million records to **geometry data type** using the above lines of code.*

Is there a way to get it in geometry data type while querying itself that would take very less time? If not, then is there a way using which I can convert 4 million records in a very short time after I fetched it from database?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595482/performance-of-geopandas-when-converting-from-pandas-wkt), it is close to duplicate. OP there seems to have better performance. Apart from that, I can only propose using `multiprocessing`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it queried only one time? Then maybe this could be faster:

```
df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt(psql.read_sql(psycopg2.connect(user=user, password=postgres_password, host=host, port=port, database=database), conn)['geometry']), geometry='geometry')
```